# How to get over Usage Limits of APIs?

Tags: android, api, rest, limit

Looking around various APIs, I notice there is a very small limit of API calls a given API Key can make per day. In cases where I am only reading data from the API sources (i.e. GET http command) - what is a good strategy to get over the usage limits? 
(Below are my specific plans that i would like comments on [looking to understand how the pros do it] & also examples of API usage limits)

Walmart API allows only 5000 calls a day [link](https://developer.walmartlabs.com/API_Terms_of_Use)

Google Book API allows 1000 requests only per day

Google Places API - 1000 requests only per day... the list goes on.
[image: Google API Limits]

Here is my dilemma (using Google Places API, 1000 requests/per day as example):If I access the API every time user opens my App/Activity, the 1000 requests per day can get over very quick (even if i have just a few hundred users) - so what could be the solution here?

1. Cache data in Local SQLlite database and update only once a day per user (since in cases like google places, data is not changing very often)
2. Should I query the places API (all queries I want) from a webserver/website and then write a REST server on my webserver that my Android Apps will access? (i.e. the Android apps access the website REST server instead of the google server)

Which method 1,2, or (something else?) is the recommended approach? I am trying to understand how to the advanced developers get around this problem.

[I hope the scope of the question does not fall into 'research' as I have provided specific problem definition and approaches to solve the problem. If someone feels it does, I can provide more details]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is to enable billing and let Google charges you for using their APIs.

method 1. is a probably approach, and it will help you drives your billings down, but depending how big the app grows, it won't totally solve it.

method 2. is not allowed by their terms of service, and if/when they find it out, they will cut your access.